# Factorise confusion

Tags: factoring

> $$\dfrac{1 - (1 - a)^{n + 1} + a(1 - a)^{n + 1}}{a} = \dfrac{1 - (1 - a)(1 - a)^{n + 1}}{a}$$

Can someone please explain how this simplification works? thank you

Comment: Did you mean $a$ or $2$ in the denominator in the RHS?

Comment: For the numerator, look into factorization.

Comment: sorry, yea i mean a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u = (1-a)^{n+1}$. Then we have
$$\frac{1 - u + au}a = \frac{1 + (-1 + a)u}a = \frac{1 - (1-a)u}a.$$

Comment: Would you mind explain how did u get   $\frac{1 + (-1 + a)u}a = \frac{1 - (1-a)u}a.$  this part?? How did the opertaor being changed? sorry for this stupid question?

Comment: @stevielol $$\dfrac{1 + (-1 + a)u}{a} = \dfrac{1 + ((-1)\cdot1+(-1)\cdot(-a))u}{a} = \dfrac{1 + (-1)(1 - a)u}{a} = \dfrac{1 - (1 - a)u}{a}$$

Comment: ah thank you @an4s

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{1 - \color{red}{(1 - a)^{n + 1}} + a\color{red}{(1 - a)^{n + 1}}}{a} =$

$\dfrac{1 - [\color{red}{(1 - a)^{n + 1}} - a\color{red}{(1 - a)^{n + 1}}]}{a} =$

$\dfrac{1 - [1\cdot\color{red}{(1 - a)^{n + 1}} - a\color{red}{(1 - a)^{n + 1}}]}{a} =$

$ \dfrac{1 - (1 - a)\color{red}{(1 - a)^{n + 1}}}{a}$

And going one step further:

$ \dfrac{1 - \color{blue}{(1 - a)}\color{blue}{(1 - a)}^{n + 1}}{a}= \dfrac{1 - \color{blue}{(1 - a)}^{n + 2}}{a}$

Comment: $\dfrac{1 - \color{red}{(1 - a)^{n + 1}} + a\color{red}{(1 - a)^{n + 1}}}{a} $ is not equal

$\dfrac{1 - [\color{red}{(1 - a)^{n + 1}} - a\color{red}{(1 - a)^{n + 1}}]}{a} $  or am i wrong?

Comment: Of course it is.  $a - (b -c) = a - b + c$.